# How to change java for loop to while loop

Tags: java, for-loop, while-loop, converters

For one of my assignments, I need to modify the original code to work with a string that will be passed to another function so i'm converting this for loop to a while loop, but I cant seem to get it right. Where am I going wrong?

```
public void smallestError(double[] errorCalculation, double[] mean, double[][] ratios, int length) {

    double small = errorCalculation[0];
    computedRatios = new double[length];
    int holder = 0;
    //int x = 0;
    for (int i =0; i<7; i++)
        {
            if(errorCalculation[i] < small)
            {
                small = errorCalculation[i];
                holder = i;
            }
        }


    computedError = small;
    computedRatios = new double[length];

    for (int x = 0; x < length; x++) {
        computedRatios[x] = ratios[holder][x];
    }
    //String str1 = String.valueOf(holder);

   // bigODeter = str1;
   bigODeter = holder;

}
```

My attempt:

```
public void smallestError(double[] errorCalculation, double[] mean, double[][] ratios, int length) {

    double small = errorCalculation[0];
    computedRatios = new double[length];
    int holder = 0;
    int x = 0;

    /*for (int x = 0; x < 7; x++) {
        if (errorCalculation[x] < small) {
            small = errorCalculation[x];
            holder = x;
        }
    }*/
    while (x == 0) {
        if (errorCalculation[x] < small) {
            small = errorCalculation[x];
        }
        holder = x;
    }

    while (x == 1) {
        if (errorCalculation[x] < small) {
            small = errorCalculation[x];
            holder = x;

        }
    }

    while (x == 2) {
        if (errorCalculation[x] < small) {
            small = errorCalculation[x];
            holder = x;

        }
    }

    while (x == 3) {
        if (errorCalculation[x] < small) {
            small = errorCalculation[x];
            holder = x;

        }
    }

    while (x == 4) {
        if (errorCalculation[x] < small) {
            small = errorCalculation[x];
            holder = x;

        }
    }

    while (x == 5) {
        if (errorCalculation[x] < small) {
            small = errorCalculation[x];
            holder = x;

        }
    }

    while (x == 6) {
        if (errorCalculation[x] < small) {
            small = errorCalculation[x];
            holder = x;

        }

        computedError = small;
        computedRatios = new double[length];

        for (x = 0; x < length; x++) {
            computedRatios[x] = ratios[holder][x];
        }
        String str1 = String.valueOf(holder);

        bigODeter = str1;

    }
}
```

Also, I had to convert the holder from an int to a String because we have to convert it.

Comment: Not my downvote, but why do you need to convert from a `for` to `while` loop in the first place?

Comment: `for (int i =0; i<7; i++)` is maybe the same as `while (i++ < 7)`

Comment: also in your code `x` is never incremented

Comment: Any loop, doesn't matter if it's `for` or `while`, will run indefinitely if the condition being checked never changes.  What would cause `x == 0` (or any of the other conditions) to change?  And why are you replacing *one* loop with *several* loops?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen It's not a bad thing to do (for practice) if one doesn't know how to do it (which obviously is the case here). Clearly one does not understand the for loop if one can't convert it to a while loop.

Comment: I need to pass a string to another function rather than an int like it is initially, I have bigODeter declared globally. So instead of x == 0, x == 1, etc.. I should have x == "O(N)", x == "O(1)".. etc but working on that part now, just need to figure out the while loop, or is there another way? @David

Comment: @DavidA: It's not clear to me at all what the difference between a `for` loop and a `while` loop has to do with *anything* that you're describing.  These two kinds of loops are nearly identical.  The only difference is that the `for` syntax has three lines of code in the loop declaration, whereas the `while` syntax has one line of code in the loop declaration and the others are outside of the declaration.  `for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++) { }` is the same as `int x = 0; while (x < 10) { x++; }`  Whatever you're trying to do, you're stuck on the *very* wrong thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one...

```
public void smallestError(double[] errorCalculation, double[] mean, double[][] ratios, int length) {

double small = errorCalculation[0];
computedRatios = new double[length];
int holder = 0;
//int x = 0;
  int i =0;
  while (i<7)
    {
        if(errorCalculation[i] < small)
        {
            small = errorCalculation[i];
            holder = i;
        }
    i++;
    }


computedError = small;
computedRatios = new double[length];

int x= 0;

while (x < length){

      computedRatios[x] = ratios[holder][x];
      x++;

}
//String str1 = String.valueOf(holder);
// bigODeter = str1;
   bigODeter = holder;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This helped a lot!